# cloth simulation

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation, parent

I am currently trying an animation that pulls out paper out of the box.
As a paper, I used a plane and applyed cloth simulation. To move it, I've made several hooks and attached a key to it but the cloth doesn't seem to follow the hook.
Can anybody help please? File is below.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15xDT-3WuYFn1ia4JX9qpo0e1KIIzdxx8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i don't see any hooks modifier in your file!?

Comment: Sorry I may have attached the wrong file.
I changed the URL, could you check please?

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 2):

you just forgot to set the pin group "pin" here:

[image]

result:

[image]